# pydev issue with gobject

Tags: python, linux, pydev, gobject

It seems that Pydev (1.5.4) on Eclipse (3.5.1) with Python 2.6 isn't able to correctly cross-reference the package `gobject`.  Putting `import gobject` works OK but any more than that (e.g. `class X(gobject.GObject)` causes Pydev to report "unresolved reference" errors.

What could be the problem?

Note that every other package I use doesn't trigger this error.

Comment: I don't know what could be happening but you could report this as a bug to PyDev: http://pydev.org/faq.html#how_do_i_report_a_bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to [this limitation of PyDev](http://pydev.org/faq.html#i_have_a_library_installed_and_pydev_does_not_find):

> I have a library installed and Pydev
>   does not find it
>
> Well, problems have been reported on
>   Mac and Linux, and the main reason
>   seems to be symlinks. Pydev will only
>   find extensions that are 'really'
>   below the python install directory.
>   This happens because the 'less common
>   denominator', which in this case is
>   windows, does not have symlinks. A
>   workaround to this problem includes
>   manually adding the given folder
>   installation to the pythonpath or
>   changing the installation of the
>   package to be under the site-packages
>   folder.

To adjust for this limitation, find the **absolute path** to the library and update the libraries associated with the interpreter for Pydev.