# Undefined variable from import: GObject

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to build a GTK+ application with PyDev 2.7.1 in Eclipse Helios on ubuntu 12.04.
But Python cannot find the class gobject.GObject. I installed any gobject library i could find and tried several external library paths, like mentioned in these post 
[pydev issue with gobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106349/pydev-issue-with-gobject) and [How to resolve these unresolved imports in PyDev ( eclipse )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098483/how-to-resolve-these-unresolved-imports-in-pydev-eclipse).

but anything worked so far. Does anyone know a workaround/solution ?

Regards
Ck

```
  import pygtk
  pygtk.require("2.0")
  import gobject

  class MyClass(gobject.GObject):
  ...
```

the import

```
  from gi.repository import GObject
```

doesn't work eather.

I also added /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7, in which the gtk-2.0, gi and gobject modules are located, to my PYTHONPATH in Eclipse, but it made no difference.

I added a forced builtin for gi to the interpreter as well, but without effect.

here a bug is reported http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649861 , but also that it has been solved since pygobject 3.0.2-4. my version of python-gobject is 3.2.2-1

The import works for the test script executed in PyDev and in a terminal:

```
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk

class Test(GObject.GObject):
    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        print ("test")

    def main(self):
        print ("Import has worked")

print (__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    test = Test()
    test.main()
```

When I apply this to class MyClass(GObject.GObject) I get the following error:

*ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ImportError('When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject".',))*

There is no `import gobject`, only `from gi.repository import GObject`.

Comment: Does the import succeed if you run a script with `from gi.repository import GObject` in a terminal? For example, I have no problem running [Python script that uses Gtk](http://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712) on Ubuntu 12.04 without any sys.path manupulation or installing additional packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.

```
import gobject


class MyClass(gobject.GObject):

def __init__(self, channelstrip, name, s_type, mainWin):
    gobject.GObject.__init__(self)
```